# Manage/Delete cookies of working WebView2

Tags: c++, winapi, webview2

I am running Edge WebView2 with some login page loaded there. I want to make an automatic login.

To do that I need to remove current cookies. I can’t do that via js because they are httponly.
For Edge beta browser I wrote simple Chrome extension for deleting cookies, but I can’t run an extension in WebView2 (or can?).

Also I know where the WebView2 cookies file is situated but I can’t change it while Webview is running.

The only way to do that in WebView is open DevTools, I removed them in application tab.

Any ideas on how to delete that cookies?

---

I would appreciate at least example of WebView2 page loading with custom header (where I can specify cookies) in **c++**.

Comment: WebView2 does not yet have a fully featured cookies API, but they have a devtools API that you can use to issue dev tools commands. This is actually the recommended approach to deleting cookies. I'll try to pull up some links and post an answer if nobody else does

Comment: @Human-Compiler If you provide me an example, or at least a link to study I will be very appreciated. Also, seems I saw seems similar to what You are talking about, there was a method called like `...calldevtoolsmethodasync` or something like that, but it was for C#

Comment: Yeah, that's the API. Most, if not all, of the C# API is also available as C++ APIs. If you haven't already seen it, Microsoft has a [Browser Example Repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Browser) which is a good source to reference -- where they use this API to clear all cookies (which I've also linked in my answer). There's an open request for a proper cookie API, but for the time being the recommendation is to use the devtools API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** There is now an official [ICoreWebView2CookieManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2cookiemanager) that can be used for managing cookies. Microsoft documents this API *extremely* well -- so its best to check their documentation.

With this new API, its just a matter of calling either `DeleteCookie` to delete a single cookie, `DeleteCookies` to remove all cookies from a domain, or `DeleteAllCookies` to clear all cookies under the same profile.

<sup>(The original answer is retained below)</sup>

---

WebView2 is still in active development, and does not yet have a cookies API -- although it is a [request that they are aware of](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/4).

The currently recommended approach to clearing/deleting cookies is to use [`ICoreWebView2::CallDevToolsProtocolMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-622/icorewebview2#calldevtoolsprotocolmethod) and issue a [`Network`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/) command. This is also what Microsoft demonstrates in their [sample browser application](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Browser/blob/4c936a8a9610f25622a695d72704a9e1b23fb01c/BrowserWindow.cpp#L815) to delete all cookies. Using the `DevTools` API will still work, even if front-end UI devtools are not enabled in the application.

The parameters supplied to the command must be in JSON format, so if you want to delete a specific cookie using [`Network.deleteCookies`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-deleteCookies), you will need to supply `{"name":"<cookie name>;"}` to delete `<cookie name>`:

```cpp
m_view->CallDevToolsProtocolMethod(L"Network.deleteCookies", L"{\"name\": \"<cookie name>\";}", nullptr);
```

Or alternatively you can delete *all* cookies with [`Network.clearBrowserCookies`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-clearBrowserCookies):

```cpp
m_view->CallDevToolsProtocolMethod(L"Network.clearBrowserCookies", L"{}", nullptr);
```

**Note:** The `CallDevToolsProtocolMethod` is issued *asynchronously*, and so if you may need to supply a handler argument if you are needing the cookie deleted before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code to create, update and get the cookies from WebView

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wil/com.h>
#include "WebView2.h"
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
std::wstring uri = L"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/";
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webview;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_2> webview2;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2CookieManager> cookieManager;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Cookie> cookie;

void WebView2Initialise(HWND & hWnd)/*HWND of MainWindow, call this after Window initialisation */ {
//Create a single WebView within the parent window
//Locate the browser and set up the environment for WebView
CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
        [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT{

            // Create a CoreWebView2Controller and get the associated CoreWebView2 whose parent is the main window hWnd
            env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(hWnd, Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
                [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller) -> HRESULT {
                    if (controller != nullptr) {
                        webviewController = controller;
                        if (webviewController)
                        {
                            webviewController->get_CoreWebView2(&webview);
                            if (webview)
                            {
                                webview->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&webview2));
                                webview2->get_CookieManager(&cookieManager);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Add a few settings for the webview
                    // The demo step is redundant since the values are the default settings
                    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Settings> settings;
                    
                    webview->get_Settings(&settings);
                    if (settings)
                    {
                        settings->put_IsScriptEnabled(TRUE);
                        settings->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(TRUE);
                        settings->put_IsWebMessageEnabled(TRUE);
                    }

                    // Resize WebView to fit the bounds of the parent window
                    RECT bounds;
                    GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
                    webviewController->put_Bounds(bounds);
                    std::wstring uri = L"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/";

                    // Schedule an async task to navigate to Bing
                    webview->Navigate(uri.c_str());

                    if (cookieManager)
                    {
                        //Create Cookies
                        cookieManager->CreateCookie(L"CookieName", L"CookieValue", uri.c_str(), L"/", &cookie);
                        cookieManager->AddOrUpdateCookie(cookie.get());

                        cookieManager->GetCookies(
                            uri.c_str(),
                            Callback<ICoreWebView2GetCookiesCompletedHandler>(
                                [](HRESULT error_code, ICoreWebView2CookieList* list) -> HRESULT {
                                    std::wstring result;
                                    UINT cookie_list_size;
                                    list->get_Count(&cookie_list_size);

                                    if (cookie_list_size == 0)
                                    {
                                        result += L"No cookies found.";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        result += std::to_wstring(cookie_list_size) + L" cookie(s) found";
                                        if (!uri.empty())
                                        {
                                            result += L" on " + uri;
                                        }
                                        result += L"\n\n[";
                                        for (UINT i = 0; i < cookie_list_size; ++i)
                                        {
                                            wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Cookie> cookie;
                                            list->GetValueAtIndex(i, &cookie);

                                            if (cookie.get())
                                            {
                                                LPWSTR value;
                                                cookie->get_Value(&value);
                                                result += value;
                                                if (i != cookie_list_size - 1)
                                                {
                                                    result += L",\n";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        result += L"]";
                                    }

                                ::MessageBox(NULL, result.c_str(), L"Cookies", MB_OK);
                                    
                                    return S_OK;
                                })
                            .Get());
                    }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I remember I solved that